# What is .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am confused can someone clarify what is .NET Framework means?

Is that an another name of Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The .Net framework is a collection libraries of classes and functions designed to extend the Common Language Runtime (CLR) and make system development easier.  Visual Studio is not required.  You can download the framework SDK and code against it in a text editor.

You could also look at the framework as the combination of the CLR and the set of libraries since it is all distributed as a unit.

Answer (score 27):

As Gary said the .NET Framework is a massive collection of libraries (assemblies) providing a big deal of functionality that dramatically eases the process of coding Windows and Rich-Client Web applications. All of these classes (and any other .net code) runs on top of the CLR (Common Language Runtime): The CLR is a runtime engine (a smart one) that provides some very neat features like Just In-Time compiling, Garbage Collection, and others. You make use of the .net framework for every application you develop using this technology. Visual Studio is really nothing more than an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) that enables you to edit, debug, build, and run your code smoothly and easily. The process of executing your .NET applications is different than other languages (C/C++ for example). Like Java, .NET code doesn't get transformed directly into native code, instead it gets transformed into some kind of a middle layer language named IL (Intermediate Language), then when you run your application, the CLR (specifically the JIT part of the CLR), compiles this IL into a native code in order to be executed. This middle layer is providing a whole deal of flexibility and portability; because of its existence, you can run your .NET code on some Linux boxes now.

Sorry if I made it too long or rather too boring for ya, I actually liked to have someone  give me some details when I was right there in your place few years ago.

Comment: as a new buddy to .net, I just want to know the differece between MSIL and java Obj. I heard java is also platform independent with the help of intermediate code generation. Sorry if I am wrong

Answer (score 11):

At the ten-thousand foot view,  .Net is essentially the same thing as Java, just made by Microsoft instead of Sun (and with everything that implies.)

Starting at about 9000 feet is where we point out that the two systems are utterly different from the ground up, are totally incompatible, but solve roughly the same problems in the same way philosophically, if not technically.  Namely - they're both a combination of Virtual Machine Runtime running VM-specific bytecode and shipped with a massive library of pre-written code, libraries and widgets, as well as letting the VM handle things like memory management and garbage collection.

Answer (score 4):

.Net is a competitor in a way to Java.  But it's a lot more than that I think.  Each have strengths and weaknesses but the key issues are:

- .Net provides a framework of classes so that you don't have to write your own code.  Eg. Windows forms, encryption libraries, network libraries, web libraries etc.
- Garbage collection (automated memory management)

[MSDN .Net Framework Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The .Net framework is a software development platform developed by Microsoft. The framework was meant to create applications, which would run on the Windows Platform. The first version of the .Net framework was released in the year 2000.
The version was called .Net framework 1.0. The .Net framework has come a long way since then, and the current version is 4.6.1. The .Net framework can be used to create both - Form based and Web based applications. Web services can also be developed using the .Net framework.
The framework also supports various programming languages such as Visual Basic and C#. So developers can choose and select the language to develop the required application. In this chapter, you will learn some basics of the .Net framework
for more :-
http://dotnetframeworktut.blogspot.in/2017/08/whatis.html