# .net- framework and .net general

Tags: .net

what is .net? the framework and clr

Comment: Closers, see the FAQ: _"No question is too trivial or too "newbie"_. Point to a duplicate or enhance the text a little.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886213/what-is-net-framework

Comment: What information resources have you checked so far? Obviously none ...

Answer (score 3):

.NET is Microsoft's marketing name for a number of new technologies. Because it's such a wide ranging collection, it's hard to define exactly what it *is*.

CLR is the Common Language Runtime, which is a bytecode language and interoperability rules that make it easier to build languages the interact well with one another. For example, before .NET making Visual Basic call C functions was awkward and error prone. In .NET, Visual Basic can call C# seamlessly.

Comment: "it's hard to define exactly what it is" Indeed, and that makes this a pretty good question actually.

Comment: It's not that hard at all really.  See AZ's answer for the usual definition.

Comment: @Greg, calling *C* (not C#) functions in any .NET language is still awkward and error prone (eg. pinvoke).  Your example is not correct as you compare calling C functions from VB to calling C# functions in VB.NET.  Completely different thing.

Comment: @Ash: Yes, well my example wasn't perfect. The C interface problem you mention is more an issue that C simply isn't a CLR language than any failing of the .NET platform. However, before .NET, C was the "de facto" systems language for Windows. After .NET, the systems language is arguably C#.

Comment: @Greg, No problems, just wanted to add the comment as it can be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

.NET is an application platform composed of 3 parts:

- the CLR - a runtime able to execute CIL(common intermediate language) code. It is composed of a JIT (just in time compiler) that complies intermediate code into native code on the fly as the application executes, a garbage collector responsible for memory management, and a loader responsible for loading assemblies, classes etc. (putting all code together to be executed by the JIT)
- the .NET library - an extensive library that provides basic system functionality as well as advanced implementations to some common used functionality (XML processing, database access, GUI programming, Web infrastructure etc.)
- a set of compilers that translate code written in the programing language of your choice (VB, C#, C++, F#, Python, Ruby etc.) to CIL code and package that into an assembly or exe

Comment: Good answer.  One point, the .NET library is more commonly called the "Base Class Library" or "Framework Class Library".

Comment: And CIL is more commonly known as MSIL.

Comment: it was named MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language) in the early days on .NET. After they standardized the runtime spec they had to change the name (now it's an international standard, not a Microsoft proprietary thing).